# Separate tables for user info and optional user info or one table?

Tags: database-design

I'm creating a site with users, and users will have various profile fields. I see a lot of systems will have a table `user` and another table called `user_profile` or something similar. `user_profile` will be a key => value table, with one row for each attribute and a column linking to a row in `user`.

I'm wondering if there is a good reason to do this, or is having a single table fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a separate table makes it easier to add and remove profile options during the life of your application.  Without that you have to change the `user` table schema each time which will potentially also cause bigger app code changes.

Comment: +1. Good point. I was only able to come up with one reason of there potentially being lots of empty column data in case of many extended attributes.